# resistor selection for TPS3700DDCR undervoltage circuit

Tags: voltage, batteries, hysteresis, undervoltage

I am designing an undervoltage circuit for a lipo battery project. I found this tutorial [here](https://www.digikey.com/eewiki/display/Motley/Simple+Undervoltage+and+Overcurrent+Protection+for+Lithium-Ion+and+Lithium+Polymer+Batteries) which lead me to the [TPS3700](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps3700.pdf?HQS=TI-null-null-digikeymode-df-pf-null-wwe&ts=1593365702543). I am wanting the undervoltage condition to be 3 volts. The part that I am hung up on is choosing the right resistors for the under and over voltage conditions. At the bottom of page 16 of the datasheet, it says `Rt=R1+R2+R3` and `Select a value for RT such that the current through the divider is approximately 100 times higher than the input current at the INA+ and INB– terminals.`
I'm having trouble figuring out this value. The max current that would be going through the power rail is 650 milliAmps.
Also the equations for `R3` and `R2` have a term `Vit+` which is defined as `Positive-going input threshold voltage`. Texas Instruments also says it's `The input threshold voltage when the input voltage is rising.`, but this doesn't really give me much detail on how to calculate it. I calculated `Vit+` from the tutorial and found this value to be around `.4001` I used this value along with their `Rt` for my resistors and assembled the circuit below:
[image]

boost gate just leads to a mosfet that controls a 3.7 to 5V boost circuit. Will these resistors cause the undervoltage condition to be 3V? The specific values for the battery I am using is 3.7V 800mAh.

Comment: The reason they say "100 times higher" is that they want what's also called a "stiff divider." That only means that they don't want the tiny currents required by the **INA+** and **INB-** inputs (they need a little bit of current to simply work, at all) to modify the voltages produced by the external resistor divider series chain. Making the current through the resistors many times higher ensures that the tiny current requirements of the inputs won't affect the designed voltages used by the window comparator. You could use 50X or 500X instead if you wanted, but the basic idea is the same.

Comment: I could draw you a nice diagram with arrows and stuff that would make this pretty clear without a lot of equations. But the basic idea is simple. If you have a **huge waterfall** of current flowing through the resistors themselves, from (+) to GND, then someone (those inputs) "taking small cupfuls" won't be noticed by the waterfall itself. It just won't be seen. But if you make the waterfall a tiny trickle itself instead, then those "small cupfuls" will be noticed and will affect the waterfall in a bad way. Kind of like that?

Comment: See also [their own referenced white paper on the subject](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva450a/slva450a.pdf?ts=1593492752351). I know it's a lot to read, but the basic kernel of the idea threads throughout it. They have a really nice "figure 2" to look at, too. So you can see, at a glance, the impact of more or less "waterfall current."$$$$If you are good with equations, I'd be happy to discuss sensitivity equations that provide a really good perspective. It might be useful to others, as well. But you have to like equations a lot. Even something this simple can involve calculus, you know.

Comment: Great question, so I'll +1 it!

Answer (score 0):

You can double check your resistor values by using the simulation tool ([Tine TI](https://www.ti.com/tool/TINA-TI)) from Texas Instrument. [Here](https://www.ti.com/lit/tsc/sbvm242) you can download a circuit similar to yours and adjust it accordingly.

Unless I understood it wrong, you are trying to design a window comparator, meaning that the boost converter will be enable if \$3V<V_{DD}<4.3V\$. Right now you are not making use of the overvoltage comparator (`OUTB` is disconnected), thus only the undervoltage feature is active. I modified the your resistor values and the output connection in order to turn on the boost gate when:

Ramp up: \$3.2V < V_{DD} < 4.34\$

Ramp down: \$2.84V < V_{DD} < 3.94\$

[image: circuit]

Comment: is the difference between 3.2V and 3V the `Vit+`?

Comment: As far as I understood, `Vit+` is given in the datasheet and it is 400mV. That's how I calculated the values.